# run a shell script on terminal if terminal is idle for few minutes in linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, shell-script

i can get terminal idle time by `w` command as follows

```
$ w
 14:37:58 up 2 days, 20:16,  2 users,  load average: 0.12, 0.16, 0.14
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
charan   tty7                      Fri18    2days  3:53   0.33s gnome-session --session=ubuntu
charan   pts/0    :0               14:33    6.00s  0.19s  0.00s w
```

and `tty` gives me current tty as bellow

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

And i want to run a shell script in same tty when idle time is more than some `x` value
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Getting idle time in linux](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2008/04/20/getting-idle-time-in-unix/) will be useful for you. There is C source that you can use.

Comment: I havnt used Ruby, So i am not able to run it in my system :(